# Convolution of two square pulses

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I want to convolve two square pulses. One pulse say X starts from 0 to R.Other pulse say Y starts from -R to 0.Now to convolve these two pulses I just flip the pulse X and then move it to -infinity.Now, to convolve I will pass this pulse through pulse Y. The result will be a triangular waveform which starts from -R+(1/2) and ends at 0+(1/2).Am i right?

Comment: "Flipping the pulse and moving it to $-\infty$" is a dreadful way to begin. Just "flip it" and note that this is the position for zero offset, that is, if $h = f*g$, then $$h(0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(-x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ To calculate $h(\tau)$ for positive values of $\tau$, move $g(-x)$, the "flipped over" pulse $\tau$ units to the right; for negative values of $\tau$, move it to the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t understand your notation +(1/2). Your geometric intuition is good (moving one object through the other) but how to you obtains your bounds? I think the bounds should be $[-R, R]$, with peak at 0.

Think it as the sum of two independent variables $X$ with range $[0,R]$ and $Y$ with range $[-R,0]$. The sum has range $[-R,R]$.

More formally, writing explicitly a convolution of $f(x) = \mathbf 1_{x\in[0,R]}$ and $g(x) =  \mathbf 1_{x\in[-R,0]}$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
f*g (x) &= \int f(t) g(x-t) dt \\
&= \int_0^R g(x-t) dt \\
&= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x < -R \\
\textstyle (R+x) &\text{if } -R \le x \le 0\\
\textstyle (R-x) &\text{if } 0  \le x \le R\\
0 & \text{if } R < x
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
These are not probability densities, just divide both $f$ and $g$ by $R$ if you wish so. Of course $f*g$ will then be the above result, divided by $R^2$.

Comment: Actually, I took convolution of two unit pulses in this online calculator.Here the triangle starts from +1/2. That confused me a little bit.  https://maxwell.ict.griffith.edu.au/spl/Excalibar/Jtg/Conv.html

Comment: I just tried, there’s no problem with this calculator. Try it by drawing your two signals as piecewise linear function, you’ll find just the above result. The animation is fine, it gives good intuition.

Comment: Another way to get some intuition is to consider the graphe of $f(x)g(y)$. Then you move the line $x+y=z$ accross this graph ($z$ is the moving parameter); at each position of this line, you compute an integral along the line. The result is $f*g(z)$.